# Error: Authorization Failed When Downloading Model from CivitAI

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface, stable-diffusion

issues while attempting to download files through the Civitai API using your API key. The error message states that the download is being aborted, and it receives a response status of 400, indicating a client-side error.

been trying to get a model to download from civitai model platform for stable diffusion the api key should of allowed me to download the model because without it am getting an unauthorization to download throw civitai[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4We2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SamRI.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review the rules and guidelines before posting.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In particular:  Do not post pictures of code.  Include enough code here so that someone could reasonably reproduce the issue.  You should also provide some evidence that you believe your queries are well-formed in the first place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.